# Making a selector to put objects into an array in jquery

Tags: jquery, selector

Good evening everyone. I am re-learning jquery and the selectors are still vexing me. I want to put several elements into an array of objects but all selectors I tried thus far returned empty objects like Object { length: 0, prevObject: {…} }.
I just want to create a selector that lets me find specific elements reliably. Here comes the HTML of the elements I want to put into the array.

```
<span align="center" id="r1">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
</span>
<br>
<span align="center" id="r2">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
</span>
<br>
<span align="center" id="r3">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
</span>
```

That would be the last selector I have tried.

```
var mycell = $('span').eq(reihe);
      getID(mycell);
      var mycont = $(mycell, 'div').eq(spalte);
      console.log("Mycont: " + mycont);
```

The variables reihe and spalte are defined and take on values between 0 and 2. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You really need to define your question more clearly.  *"put several elements into an array"* doesn't really tell us which elements or what you want an array for.   If you're using jquery, then keep them in a jquery object/collection, not an `array`.

Comment: You could also include *all* the *relevant* code (ie not just all your code) - eg what's `getID()` do?  For a function named `getXXX` I would expect it to return something so you might have `var id=getID...`,   If you use `.eq(0)` then you'll get the first element - that's not an `array`, but it is a jquery collection containing only one element.

Comment: Don't debug by using `+` on objects, you'll just get `[Object object]` - use a comma: `console.log("Mycont: ", mycont);`

Comment: Your issue is with `$(mycell, 'div')` - should be `$('div', mycell)` as `mycell` is the container so goes last.  You could use `mycell.find("div").eq...` which is easier to read/understand.  https://jsfiddle.net/ayewsvdq/

Comment: Dear mr. @freedomn-m, the elements I want to put in my array are the divs in my HTML. GetID uses a selector that returns "undefined" to get the ID of the object (it alerts the ID). I would like to run the selector for my divs in a loop to add all the divs into an array so I can address them far more easily (like mydivs[2]). As said above I am relearning jquery and have an extremely hard time with the selectors.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you want: https://api.jquery.com/toArray/  `var arr = $("span").eq(reihe).find("div").toArray()` will give you an array of *DOM* objects - so if you want to use jquery methods, you have to re-jquery them, eg `$(arr[1]).text()`  https://jsfiddle.net/9gxqrbk5/